# Call to undefined function imageconvolution()

Tags: php, image, thumbnails

I use a php script that generates thumbnails. On my local server everything works but when I commit it the remote server throws 'Call to undefined function imageconvolution()'. I read something about GD library and saw that it is enabled on both servers (local and remote). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Imageconvolution()` was introduced in 5.1.0. Have you checked to see that the version running on the server is at least that version?

Edit: Ahhh, Ubunutu aye? That old chestnut.

Ubuntu doesn't compile with PHPs GD support due to security reasons. It uses generic GD. There is a function [here](http://forum.junowebdesign.com/share-php-script/25457-simple-replication-imageconvolution-function.html) that replicates the functionality, but it isn't anywhere near as fast apparently.

If you have proper access to the server, you can compile proper GD support into it. Instructions: http://www.howtoforge.com/recompiling-php5-with-bundled-support-for-gd-on-ubuntu

Comment: PHP Version 5.2.4-2ubuntu5.7 (the problem server)